# I need to allow negative numbers into this function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

this function does the following

- doesn't allow characters
- allows backspace
- has a high limit
- has a low limit
- has a minimun step size of 0.1 ie no number less than 0.1 ie not 0.01

what is not working are allowing negative numbers into the function

```
<html>
    <input id="setPoint" type="text" name="setPoint" onkeydown="myFunction(event,-80, 150)"   />

<script>


function myFunction(e, low, high) {
  console.log("low" + low);
  console.log("high" + high);

  var nextValue = e.target.value + e.key;
  console.log("NEXT VALUE:" + nextValue);
  if (e.which == 8) { // allow backspace
    return;
  }
  if (!/^(\d+)?([.]?\d{0,1})?$/.test(nextValue)) {
    e.preventDefault(); // non-number, don't allow
  }
  if (nextValue > high) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if(nextValue< low){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: @Spectric could you please revise your regex to allow for negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

Your regex was nearly there, however it needed a few additions. Try this regex instead:

```regex
/^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

Your current implementation also didn't allow for, eg, `10.24`, the above should work fine with that. If that was intentional, just change the `\d+` to `\d` - this'll ensure that, if the user does enter a `.`, they at least have one number after.

Comment: I can't award this as the correct answer because I cant get it to work, when you refer to \d- which one are your refereeing to the first of the second one or both